# why can I assign array[i] for a static array of length i in c?

Tags: arrays, stack, c99

Let's assume I want to build myself a c like "string".
Why does this code not throw an error when I assign array[6]?
Does char array[6] not give me index 0-5? Has this something to do with stack vs heap?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char array[6];
    array[6]='\0';

    if (array[6]=='\0'){
        printf("yes");
    }
    else printf("no");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's called [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: so the answer is: because the makers of my compiler tried to be nice and it does something that is not defined in the standard?

Comment: No, it's because nothing in the standard says the compiler *must* crash if you access an element that's out of bounds.  See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior or this article: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/07/what-is-undefined-behavior.html

Comment: okay, it's just something I've come to expect from python. (which throws an out of bounds error)-  that's one of those sharp edges of c/c++.


Quote from the linked answer:
"
Undefined behavior is one of those aspects of the C and C++ language that can be surprising to programmers coming from other languages (other languages try to hide it better). Basically, it is possible to write C++ programs that do not behave in a predictable way, even though many C++ compilers will not report any errors in the program!"

this must be a common question so thank you for taking the time again.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first look at `array[0]` which  is just a pointer to the first character. By giving the array notation with a char type you have said that `array[1]` should offset the pointer by **1 byte**(size of a char). So when you say `array[6]` you are moving the pointer outside of the allocated memory block which will cause undefined behaivour.

Comment: I know it's wrong, but why does it even let me assign outside of allocated memory?

Comment: That is because the array is just syntactic sugar for pointer arithmetic. It's just moving the pointer around which is perfectly valid.

Comment: To clarify your pointer will still be pointing on a valid memory location so it is fine for you to retrieve or store value on those locations.